# Default project layout of Java projects by Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a new Gradle guy who try to create a Java project by gradle build configuration file.

I had a build.gradle in my project folder /example with content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

However, after I built the project

```
gradle build
```

I didn't see my src/main/java and src/test/java anymore.

How can I create a project layout of java with gradle configuration file ?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly create a new Java project you can use an Init gradle plugin (as it was mentioned in the comments). This plugin is shipped with Gradle by default and you can run it's `init` task just from the command line. This task will create project layout and even with the build.gradle and settings.gradle files. You just have to call this task and provide a project type you want to create as task's argument:

```
gradle init --type java-library
```

in the folder, there you want to create your project. But if you already has a build.gradle file there, the task will be skipped, so, you have to do it in some empty project. Just calling the `build` task won't create any layout for you.